# Firebase security

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing an Android app.

I want to simply instantiate a Firebase object with some kind of `secret` so it's only able to be used on my code.

Now, anyone can access and modify my data. How do I avoid that?

I tried to do something like this on `rules`:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth == 'somepass'"
    }
}
```

But where do I put that string on my reference?

How do I simply do that?? I don't want to authenticate users, but the application.

Comment: Start with the [security quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html). It covers the basics of securing data, as well as a great intro to simple login and use of the auth variable.

Answer (score 4):

Take look at this :
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/auth.html

You have to generate a token in the server side to authenticate your user.

If you use node.js, you have to do that :

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require('./firebase-token-generator-node.js');
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET);
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({'passKey': 'somepass'});`
```

And then, in your security configuration :

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.passKey == 'somepass'"
    }
}
```

If you don't have any server, you can use simple login. See : https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

I hope it helps !